# Problem with true-type font size with JasperReport PDF files generated on an alpine docker container

Tags: fonts, alpine-linux

On an alpine-linux based docker container, I'm running a java application producing a PDF report using JasperReport library.
While on my windows development  machine my program generates a pixel-perfect report,
when run into the container, it looks like that the font size is not correctly calculated, and I get some parts of the report
where the text is truncated or goes to head or where the part of the report are stretched.
Noticeably, If I run the very same program on an ubuntu-based docker image, similar issues don't occur.
I presume that Ubuntu images are somehow better suited to render true type fonts; the problem is that ubuntu images are by far more resource demanding than alpine images.
Is there anything I can try to solve this issue ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share the commands you're trying to run?
There's a chance you'll need to install a fonts package to achieve similar results under Alpine Linux.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and sorry for the delay in getting back to you.
The Dockerfile I use to build my docker image contains this instructions:

`FROM openjdk:8-alpine  
USER root  
....  
RUN apk update  
RUN apk add tzdata  
RUN cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome /etc/localtime  
RUN echo "Europe/Rome" >  /etc/timezone  
RUN apk add iputils   
RUN apk add busybox-extras   
RUN apk add bash bash-doc bash-completion   
RUN apk add fontconfig  
RUN fc-cache -f && rm -rf /var/cache/*  
...`
Is there anything missing ?

Comment: You will need to make sure the fonts required by the report are also installed.
what fonts are you using in the report?
are those fonts available in one of fonts packages shipped with alpine-linux? can you install them? see https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/font-noto and https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=*font*&branch=edge&arch=x86_64 ?

Comment: if you're using Microsoft fonts, perhaps this package `msttcorefonts-installer` would help. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/438269/29530